# T-SQL multiple order by clauses

Tags: t-sql, sql-order-by

Is it possible to have multiple order by clauses in a select statement?  Can I do something like this?

```
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM [Db].[dbo].[Schedules] 
where (datepart(hour, [Arrival]) >= datepart(hour, getdate()))  
order by abs( (datepart(hour, [Arrival]) - datepart(hour, getdate()))*60 + datepart(minute, [Arrival]) - datepart(minute, getdate()))
order by [Arrival]
```

Reason I need second order by is to ensure records are returned in increasing Arrival times.

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a comma separated list:

```
SELECT 
  TOP(5) * 
FROM 
  [Db].[dbo].[Schedules] 
where 
  (datepart(hour, [Arrival]) >= datepart(hour, getdate()))  
order by 
  abs( 
    (datepart(hour, [Arrival]) - datepart(hour, getdate()))*60 + datepart(minute, [Arrival]) - datepart(minute, getdate())
     ),
  [Arrival]
```

Comment: Gave that a quick try but results are not returned ordered by Arrival.  Is there something else?

Comment: They will be ordered first by your abs() function results, then (for all records where that is the same value) ordered by Arrival.  Make sure that your abs() results have duplicates that can be sorted within.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Put Arrival first and abs function second and that did it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Don't repeat the ORDER BY twice. Simply separate your items with commas.

```
SELECT TOP(5) * 
    FROM [Db].[dbo].[Schedules] 
    where (datepart(hour, [Arrival]) >= datepart(hour, getdate()))  
    order by abs( (datepart(hour, [Arrival]) - datepart(hour, getdate()))*60 + datepart(minute, [Arrival]) - datepart(minute, getdate())), 
             [Arrival]
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by essentially stacks.

So if you have a clause like `order by duration, arrival`  SQL will first try to order by duration, and then by arrival for each value of duration.